# Makefile to compile a class with main opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, makefile

I hope you're all fine. 
 
I'm learning opencv (c++) currently and I'm trying to compile a "main.cpp" with a class called "Algorithms"(.h and .cpp) and for some reason I get an error like this one when trying :

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv4` `pkg-config --libs opencv4` src/Algorithms.cpp -o obj/Algorihtms.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:15: obj/Algorithms.o] Error 1
```

Here is my makefile:

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv4`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv4`

B = bin
O = obj
S = src
FLAGS = -c -Wall

all: $(O) $(B) $(B)/main

$(B)/main: $(O)/Algorithms.o 
    g++ $(FLAGS) -ggdb $(S)/main.cpp -o $(O)/main.o 
    
$(O)/Algorithms.o: 
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(S)/Algorithms.cpp -o $(O)/Algorihtms.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs


$(O):
    mkdir $(O)

$(B):
    mkdir $(B)

clean: $(O) $(B)
    rm -rf $(O)
    rm -rf $(B)
```

(Opencv is installed and I know that if I compile "main.cpp" alone it works, but I can't get "main.cpp" and the class "Algorithm" to compile simultaneously.)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you have both `Algorithms.cpp` and `main.cpp` as sources for the main target?

Comment: Being a noob, I'm not sure on how to do that. Would you have an very quick example please. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to link to an executable, you need to make GCC aware. The default is to compile and link. Use option `-c`:

```
$(O)/Algorithms.o: 
    g++ -c $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(S)/Algorithms.cpp -o $(O)/Algorihtms.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs
```

From the manpage:

> When you invoke GCC, it normally does preprocessing, compilation, assembly and linking.  The
> "overall options" allow you to stop this process at an intermediate stage.  For example, the -c
> option says not to run the linker.  Then the output consists of object files output by the
> assembler.

However in your case, as mentioned in my comment, the question is why you need an intermediate object file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question. 
I don't know why I didn't figure that out immediately in my makefile. 
Whatever, here is a working makefile that does the job :

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv4`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv4`

B = bin
O = obj
S = src
FLAGS = -c -Wall

all: $(O) $(B) $(B)/main

$(B)/main: $(O)/Algorithms.o 
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(S)/main.cpp -o $(B)/main $(O)/*.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs
    
$(O)/Algorithms.o: 
    g++ $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(S)/Algorithms.cpp -o $(O)/Algorithms.o 

$(O):
    mkdir $(O)

$(B):
    mkdir $(B)

clean: $(O) $(B)
    rm -rf $(O)
    rm -rf $(B)
```

I'm sure this makefile is not the most efficient and it can be improved in many ways.